# Is there a way to connect Android to PC wirelessly without WiFi?

Tags: windows-10, android, file-transfer, desktop-computer

I want to transfer data between my Android phone and PC. I have a connection to the internet via the phone, but not on the PC. I don't have administrator privileges and I can't install any app or software on it.

Is it possible to establish data transfer between those two without installing software on PC or connecting it via WiFi? Is there any application that doesn't need to be installed on PC in order to use it for this purpose or could I do it somehow over the IP address?

One app that I found is Xender, but it won't work without internet, so I am looking for something similar which is going to work.

Comment: What type of connection do you have on your devices? Wifi? Bluetooth? What is the OS of the pc?

Comment: OS is Windows 10, I don't have Bluetooth connection and while PC normally is connected to the internet, at the time when I am going to use it, it won't be. So I guess we could say that I don't have any kind of connection between those two.
Phone is connected to the internet over wireless.

Comment: Does your pc have wireless adapter? otherwise what kind of connection do you want to establish?

Comment: PC is normally connected to the internet via Ethernet cable over the router that supports wifi option. I am going to be connected to the internet over the same router, but on my phone and at that time, PC's connection is going to be disabled. Actually, PC is going to be connected to the internet for few minutes, so is there maybe a way to connect those two while they are both connected to the internet and continue data transfer after the connection on PC is disabled?

Comment: Can you install apps on the phone, and if you're on the Wifi via the phone, are they the same network?

Comment: Yes, I can do that and yes it's the same network

Comment: if your pc has neither wifi, neither bluetooth, then it's pretty difficult to set up any wireless connection, why not use cable?

Comment: Ok guys, thanks for help. I just thought that there is a way to establish some kind of private connection between those two and continue data transfer without internet later, but obviously it isn't. That's it, this question is closed :))

Comment: @niksrb I updated my answer. There are multiple ways to do this if you're on the same network, but my answer is one of a few that come to mind.

Comment: you can have wifi without internet.  bluetooth may be another option.  without installing software limits you to the unspecified software that's already installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the phone is connected to Wifi and the PC is plugged in via ethernet to the same network, you can do the following:

1. Install the "ES File Explorer File Manager" app from the Play Store.
2. Tap the top left button to expand the menu, and tap Network > Remote Manager.
3. Turn on the Remote Manager, and type the link on that screen into the Windows Explorer address bar.

This basically sets up a temporary FTP share on the phone that you can reach via Windows Explorer, allowing you to transfer files back and forth without having to install anything on the computer.

Comment: First of all as I mentioned in the title, I need to connect those two wirelessly, so I can't use USB. Also, PC does not have option to connect to the internet over wifi, so I can't use hotspot also. Bluetooth and NFC are also not an option. I guess there is no way to do what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes of course. Depending on the connection type you have though. If you have wifi connection (local network) between the phone and the PC, you can for example use a FTP client on your PC and a FTP server on your phone. Couple of examples of FTP servers that I tried and worked are [Ftp Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.theolivetree.ftpserver) & [WiFi FTP (WiFi File Transfer)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nalic.app.wifishare). For the FTP client on the PC, you might use any and there are many that wont need installations like portable version that I use of [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php).

Another method is to use a share web app like [SHAREit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lenovo.anyshare.gps&hl=en) to send files from the phone to the PC. Or [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en) which is only required for the phone and you can access your phone via browser on your PC. I used to use AirDroid but FTP later found to be quicker since I only share files (AirDroid has many other features).

You can even use sharing files and folders built in Windows features to achieve your purpose then use a proper explorer to discover the shared content. I found [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/191378/how-to-access-shared-windows-folders-on-android-ipad-and-iphone/) that suggests this and use ES Explorer which I don't **recommend** personally so pick another explorer.

Via Bluetooth, you can use an app like Bluetooth File Transfer.